# Traveling to Italy with Carta di Soggiorno

Tags: visas, italy, filipino-citizens

Am I allowed to travel from Philippines to Italy with a valid Philippines passport and Carta di Soggiorno, but without a visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [TIMATIC](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/cr/timatic) (documentation database) says :

> Italy - Destination Visa : Visa required.

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:

> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Italy.